# Can I render content from a view in a ViewComponent?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

Is it possible to write a `ViewComponent` that includes the content found between its calling tags?
Desired razer syntax in the view:

```
@model Area.ViewModels.SomeViewModel
<vc:test>
    //some content here
</vc:test>
```

I would like to then be able to render this somewhere in the `ViewComponent` view.
e.g.

```
@model ViewComponents.Models.TestViewModel

//some view component markup
@RenderBody() //(RenderBody is for layout pages, but I would like something like this)
//some more view component markup
```

I have tried `@RenderBody` and `@this.BodyContent` and can't find anything useful in the docs.

Comment: Why do you need `RenderBody` inside view component ? What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: I'm trying to write a `ViewComponent` that can have content within its tags when it is called.

Comment: I'm starting to think I may have to just rewrite my `ViewComponent` as a `TagHelper`.